# CSS Dropdown Menu Width Issues and Transparent Layer Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I am trying to accomplish the CSS Menu like the following image.

[image]

As you can see, when we hover to the Gallery, dropdown menu should be appeared and behind that dropdown menu, there should be another transparent layer which should be appeared.

But when I am creating that kind of menu, what I achieved is like the following image.

[image]

Comparing the two menu, what I am facing is two problem.

1. Dropdown Menu Width. (I would like to have dropdown menu width like
   the first photo. But when I tried to set the width of ul, I got it
   like the following image). [image]

   As you can see, width is changed, but the dropdown box should be at
   the center of GALLERY, but it isn't
2. I don't know how to add the transparent layers like the 1st photo.
   Please kindly instruct me how to.

Here are my codes.

> JSFiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/vZXvv/1/

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: have you already tried NOWRAP for width and opacity / filter:alpha for transparency?

Comment: hello,  i think my explanation is not so clear. About the transparency, I know how to do it in CSS. I just doesn't know how to add it behind the dropdown box as an another whole box

Comment: i don't quite understand what do you mean by "how to add it behind the dropdown box as an another whole box" - why do you need another whole box behind dropdown menu? will you place img/text in there?

Comment: Hello elan, oh what I mean is like this. As you see in the first photo, aside dropdown box, there's another box behind which is with transparent background right? That's the box that I don't know how to do it.

Comment: oh you mean the box that goes across the whole menu...  in your CSS do you already have it? what's it's name, so i don't look for it..

Comment: and btw - why don't you look at CSS of the above site? or is it just img?...

Comment: it's the image that I created by myself with photoshop. Do u have any other solutions ?

Comment: What width did you set to the ul, I don't experience that deffect?

Comment: solution for issue #1 - http://jsfiddle.net/yHNCS/1/

Comment: Zoltan, thanks for the solution 1. It works.

Answer (score 0):

For transparency you can use RGBA or repeat 1px png with transparency as background img.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a fix for the positioning, try this calculation:

```
$(this).mouseenter(function() {
                            var leftPos = ($(this).find("ul").width() / 2) - ($(this).width() / 2);

                            $(this)
                                .find("ul")
                                .css({
                                    "left": -leftPos
                                })

                            $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();
                        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/vZXvv/20/